# Designing a DC motor speed control circuit using PWM

Tags: transformer, dc-motor, 555, proteus

I am designing a DC motor speed control circuit. I am using a centre-tapped transformer to get a dual voltage of 12v. The problem is both the 555 timer and the motor need a positive supply and batteries are out of the option. When using the dual polarity power supply, I get a simulation failed error in Proteus. Any suggestions on how to fix the circuit is welcome.

The problem is that the power supply is not providing enough current to turn on the motor in the regular transformer design. And in the center tapped transformer design, the negative voltage can not power the 555.

My analysis is that the 555 won't work with a negative voltage but I do not know how to correct that. And the motor doesn't work with the negative voltage either. Should I change the power supply circuit or is there any way I can modify it so that it can power both the 555 and the dc motor?
P.S: It is a 12V motor

I am using a step-down transformer to take 230V to 30V then regulating it to 12V. The circuit diagram is shown below.
[image]

This is the image of the circuit when I was using a regular transformer. It didn't work too. The issue was that the transformer could not provide enough current for the motor.
[image]

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that the primary side of the transformer is "floating", having no absolute potential. Stick a ground symbol on whichever side of the primary winding you want to call "neutral".

Comment: @SimonFitch - I just tried it. No difference. The motor doesn't move at all.

Comment: Wow, I meant in the simulation, please tell me you didn't just connect earth and neutral together, or your circuit ground directly to neutral. My suggestion was *in the simulation* to make the simulator work

Comment: @SimonFitch - I know that. I did it in the simulation

Comment: Why do you need a negative voltage? A 555 won't work on a negative voltage, a real part would have burned up. Run everything on +12V. What is R4 doing? A resistor in series with your Vcc is usually a bad thing. You also need a base resistor on Q1.

Comment: @Mattman944- I was using a regular transformer before but it wasn't working which is why I switched to a centre-tapped transformer that is also not working. When I run everything on 12V, there is not enough current to power the motor efficiently. It lags and eventually just stops. R4 is not doing anything, I kind of forgot it there. And which value of resistor do I need at the base of Q1 and why?

Comment: In the split supply version GND of NE555 and emitter of Q1 must be connected to the negative supply and VCC of NE555 must be connected to GND. This way the NE555 uses the lower half of the supply with correct polarity. Try a base resistor of 100 ohm.